# Can I limit the hugepages size of dpdk?

Tags: dpdk

I have two programs, one is based on dpdk. And both use hugepages. But dpdk uses up all hugepages by default. I can't find any document about how to set the hugepages size that dpdk can use. Is there any handy way to do this? If not, I have to research dpdk source and modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of caveats, till DPDK 18.11 option `-m` and `--socket-mem` does as what @andriy states. But with the release of DPDK 19.11, there has been huge revamp in the internal logic.

For higher version than 18.11 mode use `--legacy-mem` to emulate the older memory model. But if legacy-mode is not the choice, use `--socket-limit`.

Assuming the platform is x86 (as 2MB and 1GB), as far as I recollect 2MB can be dynamically changed while 1GB can not be dynamically allocated. Hence any options passed in kernel cmd line will result in equal allocation from all NUMA.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are few command line options. The easiest is `-m <megabytes>`, but it’s internal logic might be completely wrong if you have a few NUMA nodes.

I recommend to use `—socket-mem <mbytes,mbytes,...>` instead, which allows to allocate a specific amount of megabytes per NUMA node.

For more details please see: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_eal_parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

To add, one can also use this addition to above whatever @andriy mentioned to implicitly set hard limit
`/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages` for 2MB hugepage size

Similarly for 1G on too we can do it, but that depends support.